# Jenkins SonarQube plugin: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown'

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am testing SonarQube to analysis PL/SQL. The source code is downloaded from: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples.git, using Git in Jenkins. Now in SonarQube plugin, if I just set "Path to project properties" as ${workspace}\projects\languages\plsql\plsql-sonar-runner, it gives me the above error. Here is the command I found in Jenkins job log:

```
[SonarQube_PLSQL] $ D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat -e -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.0.85.5:5432/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.dev.com/ ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=D:\edp_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube_PLSQL -Dproject.settings=D:\edp_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube_PLSQL\projects\languages\plsql\plsql-sonar-runner
D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_31 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
```

Why it's not finding the project properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the path relative to the project work space. I.e. `projects\languages\plsql\plsql-sonar-runner`.

Comment: Same error, here is the output. I have to put these properties inside "Analysis properties" to make it work. [SonarQube_PLSQL] $ D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat -e -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.2.85.5:5432/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.dev.com/ ******** * Dsonar.projectBaseDir=D:\edp_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube_PLSQL -Dproject.settings=D:\edp_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube_PLSQL\projects\languages\plsql\plsql-sonar-runner
D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the root folder of your project has “sonar-project.properties”